# Disable Pause, Stop, and Restart on windows service with Topshelf

Tags: c#, .net, service, topshelf

With a standard windows service i would use CanStop, CanShutdown, CanPauseAndContinue, and CanHandlePowerEvent to disable all of these features through the services menu, but the topshelf documentation says that these are disabled by default and they are not. I read all of the topshelf documentation on how to do this and nothing laid it out.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/issues/487) ?

Comment: @NPras cast throws an error.